# PHP, variable is not defined

Tags: php

I am trying to make sort of a captcha verification and one of my variables is not defined. Here is my code for the captcha generator:

```
<?php
    $num = rand(1,3);

    switch($num) {
        case 1:
            $img = "";
            $answer = "nov 18th";
            break;
        case 2:
            $img = "";
            $answer = "jan 19th";
            break;
        case 3:
            img = "";
            $answer = "school bad";
            break;
    }
?>
```

Now here is my code for the script that checks whether or not the captcha input was entered correctly:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    print "<br /><br />";

    $captcha = $_POST['captcha-verif'];

    if ($captcha == $answer) {
        header('Location: recommend-action.php');
    }
    else {
        print "Incorrect Captcha. <a href='music.php'>Try Again</a>";
    }
?>
```

I keep getting this message:

> Notice: Undefined variable: answer in /var/www/tts/recommend-verify-captcha.php on line 9

Comment: *"one of my variables is not defined"*. Do you expect us to guess which one? What is the specific error message that you get?

Comment: $answer is not defined, my apologies.

Comment: `case 3:` - you've omitted the `$` from your variable names.

Comment: That's what I thought. How can I transfer the data for $answer to recommend-verify-captcha.php?

Comment: You're using 2 seperate files? Seems like it and that's why. Plus, what's been said above for `case 3` `answer = "school bad";` to `$answer = "school bad";` because that also will thrown an undefined constant error. Put everything in 1 file with an `isset()`.

Comment: @HoboSapiens, what do you mean?

Comment: @CameronMontesano I mean `$answer` is a variable, but `answer` is not, although PHP is quite forgiving and you might get away with it. You'll certainly see a `Notice` in your server error log

Comment: [Edited comment, reload...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228656/php-variable-is-not-defined#comment44820363_28228656). You could also use sessions.

Comment: Oh. I accidentally removed the $ in this question, but it is in my actual file.

Answer (score 0):

You need a session variable:

```
<?php
    // start session here
    session_start();
    $num = rand(1,3);

    switch($num) {
        case 1:
            $img = "";
            // store answer in session variables. 
            $_SESSION['answer'] = "nov 18th";
            break;
        case 2:
            $img = "";
            $_SESSION['answer']  = "jan 19th";
            break;
        case 3:
            $img = "";
            $_SESSION['answer']  = "school bad";
            break;
    }
?>
```

In your second snippet make sure to start the session again.

```
<?php
    // restart session
    session_start();
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    print "<br /><br />";

    $captcha = $_POST['captcha-verif'];

    // compare $captcha against answer stored in the session
    if ($captcha == $_SESSION['answer']) {
        header('Location: recommend-action.php');
    }
    else {
        print "Incorrect Captcha. <a href='music.php'>Try Again</a>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't declare answer variable in `recommend-verify-captcha.php` so, this variable is not existed.

Based on your code, I see you want answer is result from

```
<?php
$num = rand(1,3);

switch($num) {
    case 1:
        $img = "";
        $answer = "nov 18th";
        break;
    case 2:
        $img = "";
        $answer = "jan 19th";
        break;
    case 3:
        $img = "";
        $answer = "school bad";
        break;
}?>
```

So you can do like that

```
function getCapcha(){
    $num = rand(1,3);

    switch($num) {
        case 1:
            $img = "";
            $answer = "nov 18th";
            break;
        case 2:
            $img = "";
            $answer = "jan 19th";
            break;
        case 3:
            $img = "";
            $answer = "school bad";
            break;
    }
}
```

Then use this function in your `recommend-verify-captcha.php` file , maybe like as

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    print "<br /><br />";

    $captcha = $_POST['captcha-verif'];
    $answer = getCapcha();
    if ($captcha == $answer) {
        header('Location: recommend-action.php');
    }
    else {
        print "Incorrect Captcha. <a href='music.php'>Try Again</a>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: The error comes from the second snippet of code not the first.

Comment: Not relevant since it's defined in the `case` blocks anyway.

Comment: Does not appear to change anything.

Comment: Sidenote: `answer = "school bad";` - OP says the `$` is in their code *"Oh. I accidentally removed the $ in this question, but it is in my actual file."*. `answer = "school bad";` will throw an undefined constant notice if not fixed in this answer, should anyone visit the question/answer.

Comment: Thanks .Fred. typo mistake again.

Comment: Thanks, Today is so fully typo mistake for me :(

Comment: In order for this to work, would require all code be inside the same page, since the `getCapcha()` function won't be accessible when calling the 2nd file. It should be noted in the answer in case OP doesn't know what to do with it.